# java application to emulate Bluetooth mouse

Tags: java-me, emulation, hid

I want to make a java application to emulate Bluetooth mouse(HID)
the application should **run as is** in **any java enabled touchscreen phone equipped with a acclerometer**

I have been looking around and I didnt come across existing product like it. So I was wondering if it is even possible.

Also I am comfortable with Java Standard edition but this I dont have any experience in Java ME so I seek advice on how to proceed  .